# MS Access import and append type conversion fail on date field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to import data from a text file and append it to a table in an MS Access 2010 database. All data imports and appends properly, with the exception of a date field.

The date field is in the format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

I can import the text file into a new table without issue. This works if I specify the field as text or date/time with various foramts. Where it fails is when I try to append it to an existing table. It does not matter whether the destination field data type is text or date/time.

It isn't the end of the world if I have to import the text file into a new table. But I find it very strange that I cannot import data form a text file to a text field.

If anyone can shed some light on what is causing this issue I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue last week and believe it or not it took me a full day to sort it out.

I was creating a link to an Excel document where I was importing records to a table through an import query. All good except the date field which Access had mapped it like Text (the first 80-100 records of the field were blank, then a date and then blanks again).

Long story short, I tried a number of different approaches but on all of them I was getting a *datatype mismatch* error so I ended up with the solution below.

In my import query:

```
IIF(IsNull([Date Field]),NULL,CDate([Date Field]))
```

Comment: That's how to do it. Use the query to filter and convert as needed. Then use this for appending and/or further processing.

Comment: Thanks Kostas. Dumb question but where are you actually entering that function? Are you using the import wizard? I'm trying to find where I could include a function like that in the Access 2010 import wizard, to no avail.

Comment: @MJV You won't find anywhere in the import wizard to put this. Make a link to the file you want to import and create a custom import query (from the linked file to your table) where you can place this. You wont be able to solve your problem any other way.

Answer (score -1):

Set both the excel and access table date fields as text. Import using the wizard. Then in design view change the format of the date field to your desired date format and you will have the date